# Nginx and proxy_pass ip

Tags: wordpress, nginx

i've got little problem with nginx and proxy_pass on my VPS, the configuration look like this:

```
server {

    listen 8080;
    root /var/www/;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass wordpress;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING      $query_string;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www;
    index index.html;

    location ~ ^/mihal {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass wordpress;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING      $query_string;
            include fastcgi_params; 
    }
```

}

and every time i've try to get the http://serverdomanin.com/mihal i've been redirected to http://127.0.0.1/mihal...
What should i moderate to corectly use this configuration? (under /mihal/ is wordpress instance).
Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

The redirect is generated by the service running on port 8080, which does not know the name `serverdomain.com`.

You can rewrite the redirect using the `proxy_redirect` directive.

Try this:

```
location ~ ^/mihal {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost/ http://$host/;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:8080/ http://$host/;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for details.

Comment: make sure to check if a long forgotten docker-compose file needs environment variables updated... thanks for the hint, was looking for this for a while...